# Python - How do I write a more efficient, Pythonic reduce?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree

I'm trying to build a very lightweight Node class to serve as a Python-based hierarchy search tool. See the definition below.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_


class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child_node):
        self.children.append(child_node)

    def contains(self, other_node):
        if self == other_node:
            return True
        elif other_node in self.children:
            return True
        else:
            return reduce(or_, [child.contains(other_node)
                                for child in self.children], False)

    def is_contained_by(self, other_node):
        return other_node.contains(self)

    def __eq__(self, other_node):
        return self.name == other_node.name

    def __de__(self, other_node):
        return self.name != other_node.name
```

`contains` seems to be a textbook case of functional programming (pulled directly from [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/courses/cs345/whyfp.pdf)).

Question: is there a more efficient or Pythonic way of writing `contains`? I know that `map` is usually replaced by list comprehension, but I hadn't seen a better way of doing `reduce`-based recursion.

Thanks,

Mike

===EDITED ... HERE'S THE REDONE CLASS TAKING INTO ACCOUNT THE ANSWER AND COMMENTS===

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child_node):
        # Hattip to lazyr for catching this.
        if self.contains(child_node) or child_node.contains(self):
            raise TreeError('A relationship is already defined.')    
        else:
            self.children.append(child_node)                

    def contains(self, other_node):
        # Hattip to lazyr for pointing out any() and to Jochen Ritzel for
        # eliminating the silly child check.
        return (self == other_node or
                any(child.contains(other_node) for child in self.children))

    def is_contained_by(self, other_node):
        return other_node.contains(self)

    def __eq__(self, other_node):
        return self.name == other_node.name

    def __de__(self, other_node):
        return self.name != other_node.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Sadly, I am out of upvotes for the day, but this is a very good question!

Comment: if you rename `contains` to `__contains__` then `is_contained_by()` can be implemented (if you decide to leave it) as `self in other_node`. Whether it is a good idea to traverse an entire tree in the `contains()` method is another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (not tested) that you instead of `reduce` should use `any` like this, which will stop on the first hit:

```
return any(child.contains(other_node) for child in self.children)
```

By the way, did you mean for `a.contains(b)` to return `False` when `a == b` and `len(a.children) > 0`?

**Edit**: If your tree contains a loop, like this:

```
a = Node("a")
b = Node("b")
a.add_child(a)
a.add_child(b)
```

then

```
a.contains(b)
```

will crash the program. You may want to check for this either in `contains` or in `add_child`, depending on which you use the most.

Comment: No. If a == b, it should return true. Have edited. Does it work now?

Comment: BTW, it passed my test cases, including one to test the logic error you point out above.

Comment: The whole `contains` function can be written as `return self == other_node or any(child.contains(other_node) for child in self.children)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My intention was to create a another class (Graph or Tree) that would have methods to test the integrity of a set of node names, before I even start instantiating Nodes. Thinking about the abstraction, a Node shouldn't really know if it's part of a correctly-defined tree or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure once a graph contains a loop it ceases to be a tree.  If this structure is supposed to represent a tree, then I would check for loops in add_child

Comment: Ok, I just wondered if you'd thought about it. Your edit seems to have fixed the `a.contains(a) == False` problem, by the way.